# A positive definite Hermitian (1,1) form

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Suppose $f$ is a positive smooth function, if I denote $$w=i\partial f \wedge \bar{\partial} f=i \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z_j}} dz_i  \wedge d\bar{z_j} $$
I want to show it is a positive form.
From the condition 3 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_form
$$-iw(v,\bar{v})=v_i\bar{v_j}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z_j}}.$$
For diagonal entries I have already showed that the terms are positive, but how about the other term?

Or I denote $A_{ij}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z_j}}$ and then $v^*Av=v_j\bar{v_i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z_j}}$ .
Then what is the next step?

Comment: It may help to note that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}_j} = \overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}}.$$

Comment: By using this fact, I will have the diagonal terms equal to $|v|^2\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j} \right|^2$ which are positive, but how about the other terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that - since $f$ is real-valued - we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}_j} = \overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}},$$

we can write

\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j} v_i \overline{v}_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}_j}
&= \sum_{i,j} v_i \overline{v}_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}} \\
&= \sum_i v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\Biggl(\sum_j \overline{v}_j\overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}}\Biggr) \\
&= \Biggl(\sum_i v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}\Biggr)\cdot \Biggl(\sum_j \overline{v}_j \overline{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}}\Biggr) \\
&= w\cdot\overline{w} \\
&\geqslant 0,
\end{align}

where

$$w = \sum_i v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}.$$